# Spanned disk or junction link

Tags: junction, windows-share

Win server 2008r2. Role file services. The share is more than 10 TB. A 10TB virtual disk was created on the storage and added to esxi storage. Next, 2TB disks are created and added to windows. At the OS level, the disks are glued into one spanned disk, and each time a new 2TB disk is also added if necessary to increase free space.
So it was before me. I have doubts that this is correct. How do I see how to do this:

1. In esxi, slice 500gb-1tb disks
2. In the OS, do not spanned disks, but use junk links to organize the structure of the share.

Dear experts, please tell me how best to organize a share?

....................